# port 443 is enabled and how to test the server?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I am using a windows server and I know that the port 443 is enabled on the server. How can I test the connectivity by connecting to the server remote?

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSL comes with a command line utility s_client

```
openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -showcerts
```